# Accessing Azure Mobile Service JavaScript Backend API with "Application" Permissions

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Is there a special way an API built in Azure Mobile Services with a JavaScript backend needs to be accessed?  I'm porting some code from a .NET backend to JavaScript, and I specified application permissions, but when I login it keeps saying unauthorized.

Previously, I would access it using HTTP basic authentication by using a base64 encoding of a blank user name and my application key (looked something like this ":XXX").  However, that doesn't seem to be working and I've checked the application key a half dozen times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the JavaScript backend doesn't use HTTP Basic Authentication.  Instead, you pass a header parameter called "X-ZUMO-APPLICATION" with the value of your API Key.  That will handle the authentication.